# Subquery between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

1. `Patient` table
2. `Appointment` table

I can not design query for the following question

Find all the appointments for the patient that has the highest copay (let a subquery find the patient for you)

Comment: Did you ever solve this one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the MAX() aggregate function. I would assume there is a copay column somewhere, so the subquery would look something like this:

```
SELECT patient_id
FROM patient
WHERE copay = (SELECT MAX(copay) FROM patient);
```

Then, you can join that with your appointment table to get the appointments for that patient. You can probably even make this subquery part of your ON clause, like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM appointment a
JOIN patient p ON p.patient_id = a.patient_id AND p.copay = (SELECT MAX(copay) FROM patient);
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the results for one patient:

```
select a.*
from (select top 1 p.*
      from patient p
      order by p.copay desc
     ) p join
     appointment a
     on p.patient_id = a.patient_id;
```

For multiple patients with the same highest copay, you can change `top 1` to `top 1 with ties`.